# mkdir x levels down

Tags: batch-file, mkdir

I have a folder for contracts on multiple states and each state folder has multiple contracts:

```
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State1\Contract1_number_date  
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State1\Contract2_number_date  
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State2\Contract1_number_date`  
etc...
```

I need to make 3 folders for each contract:

```
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State1\Contract1_number_date\folder1  
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State1\Contract1_number_date\folder2  
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State1\Contract1_number_date\folder3  
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State1\Contract2_number_date\folder1   
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State1\Contract2_number_date\folder2   
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State1\Contract2_number_date\folder3   
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State2\Contract1_number_date\folder1  
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State2\Contract1_number_date\folder2  
D:\Workspace\Contracts\State2\Contract1_number_date\folder3
```

I found out that `\..\` goes one level up, so `mkdir D:\Workspace\Contracts\..\folder1` makes `D:\Workspace\folder1`, but I have no idea how to go 1 or 10 folders down.

Comment: Type `mkdir /?` to find out.

Comment: Somehow my intellect cannot comprehend those instructions.

Comment: You just do it. You just go 10 down. `md D:\Workspace\Contracts\State2\Contract1_number_date\folder2` and 
 `md D:\Workspace\Contracts\State2\Contract1_number_date\folder3` etc

Comment: `cd ..` can move up one level because each directory can only have a single parent, however, when you are going down a level, there can be multiple children so it cannot work the same way.

Comment: Right now I have 17 states most of them have 2 contract and go up to 8 , adding 2 more lines to the curent code doesnt help.  
So batch it cannot go to all the second rank cildren?  
Then a better aproach would be to do this with excel then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code using `For` loops to achieve your goal:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "BaseDir=%~1"
Set "NumStates=%~2"
Set "NumContracts=%~3"
Set "NumFolders=%~4"

If Not Exist "%BaseDir%\" Exit/B
For %%A In (NumStates NumContracts NumFolders) Do If Not Defined %%A Exit/B

If /I Not "%CD%"=="%BaseDir%" CD /D "%BaseDir%"

For /L %%A In (1,1,%NumStates%) Do For /L %%B In (1,1,%NumContracts%
) Do For /L %%C In (1,1,%NumFolders%
) Do If Not Exist "State%%A\Contract%%B_number_date\folder%%C\" (
    MD "State%%A\Contract%%B_number_date\folder%%C")
```

You would run your script, named `MakeDirs.cmd`, from the command line like this:

```bat
"MakeDirs.cmd" "D:\Workspace\Contracts" 17 8 3
```

The above should create `3` directories for `8` Contracts and `17` States inside `D:\Workspace\Contracts`.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I belive this can be usefull for the times when I need to copy files to thouse directorys. But I found that this can be achived from excel with less complecations.